# VimのNERDTreeでgrepができません。

Tags: vim

[grep_menuitem.vim](https://gist.github.com/inagaa/5141204)を利用して、NERDTreeでgrepできるようにしたいのですが、画像のようなエラーを吐き、うまくいきません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

行った手順は`grep_menuitem.vim`を`~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/`以下に配置しただけです。

なにか、情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 検索した文字列、実行したコマンド、Vim のバージョンを付け加えていただくと、解決が早まるかもしれません。先ほど osx + macvim で試した限りでは件のエラーは出ていません。（日本語マッチは怪しいですが）

Comment: @Hiroshi Yamamoto とりあえず、下記の方法で正常に動作しました。

Comment: 良かったです。今回、 mattn さんが異能力で解決努力をされていますので、差し支えなければ、[承認された回答として評価](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してさしあげてくださいませ。

Comment: まだ、信頼度が足りないので、賛成票に投票できないようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.vimrc

set grepprg=internal " 変更前
set grepprg=grep\ -nH " 変更後
```

`.vimrc`を上記のように編集し、外部grepを使うようにしたところ、正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 4):

エラーはおそらく[この行](https://gist.github.com/inagaa/5141204#file-grep_menuitem-vim-L47)で出ています。grep コマンドは外部コマンドを使いますので、その grep コマンドが入力した際の検索パターンを認識出来ないのだと思います。
尚、現在 vim が認識している grep コマンドは

```
:set grepprg?
```

で確認出来ます。

**追記**

エスパー過ぎてハズれているかもですが、空白を含んだパスで実行したり、検索パターンに空白やコマンドラインではエスケープしないといけない様な文字が含まれていませんか？

そうであれば grep コマンドに渡す際にクォートする必要があります。`grep_menuitem.vim` で grep コマンドを実行している部分を

```
exec 'silent grep -rn ' . shellescape(pattern) . ' .'
```

に修正して下さい。

**さらに追記**

`grepprg=internal` の場合は、パスにディレクトリを指定出来ません。その代りですが `**/*` という多段階層ディレクトリの検索が可能です。

上記のスクリプトファイルであれば `&grepprg` の値を見て `internal` であれば `.` の代わりに `**/*` を指定すると直ります。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。

`grep_menuitem.vim`のgrep部分を`exec 'silent grep -rn ' . shellescape(pattern) . ' .'`に変更してみましたが、同様のエラーになってします。

Comment: grepprg を確認し、`:sh` でコマンドラインに入った後、入力した内容を実行するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: `:set grepprg?`では`grepprg=internal`となります。
この場合、'Enter the search pattern:'で'hoge'と入力した場合、最終的にはどのような処理が行われているのでしょうか？

Comment: internal の場合は、:vimgrep と同じ動作になります。Windows であれば findstr という正規表現の扱えないコマンドになります。ちなみに OS は何でしょうか？

Comment: OSは Yosemiteです。

Comment: もうすこし追記してみました。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: `.vimrc`の`set grepprg=internal`を`set grepprg=grep\ -nH`にし、外部grepを使うことで、正常に動作しました。

この、プラグインは外部grepを使うことが前提なんでしょうか？

Comment: だと思います。汎用的に grepprg がどの値でも動く様にするのであれば、スクリプトを追記の様に修正すべきだと思います。特に internal の場合はエンコーディングをvimが面倒みてくれますが、grepの場合は(jvgrep等を使わないかぎり)面倒みてくれません。